# hr tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am working on phonegap and I am new to it. I want to draw a line using hr under the menu items which are displayed. but unfortunately I am unable to do so.

if somebody can help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

here is the code snippet

```
{
 success:function(res,code) {
                entries = [];
                var xml = $(res);
                var items = xml.find("item");
                $.each(items, function(i, v) {

                    category1.push($(v).find("category").text());
                    /*  $("#status").append("menu_type <b>"+menu_type+"</b><br/>");  */
                    console.log( "PRICE" + ": " +  $(v).find("menu_type").text() );


                });
                var category = category1.unique();
                var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");

                for(var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
                     var el1 = document.createElement("li");
                    var opt = category[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("a");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    el1.appendChild(el);
                    select.appendChild(el1);
                }

}
```

Comment: where are you adding hr in your code??

Comment: i dont know how to use it. but the menu item i want to display like a line drawn under it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this
`document.getElementById("ElementBelowWhichHRShouldCome").appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));`

Comment: I think you would have solved it by now, but in case you haven't there is a sample available in the below location: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/xYYbd/). Sorry for not using your code :(

Answer (score 1):

Try innerHTML. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wxv6n/

```
var doc = document;
var get = function(id){return doc.getElementById(id);};

get("foo").innerHTML = '<hr/>';
```

..and don't forget to cache your references to `document`

Answer (score 0):

After Every Menu Item,you can use this.Its pretty simple.

```
$("#menu_item").after('<hr/>');
```

[after() in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wxv6n/1/)

Comment: thanks! in fact I am new to Phonegap and i didn't work in JS Html etc too....if you can recommend some good resource it would be of great help to me... :)

Comment: are you talking about basics of jquery??

Comment: for starters in jquery..i would suggest headfirst jquery...really funny book.